# Android Studio: Drawable xml preview not working

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, preview

Last time I did this, it worked. But now, my Android Studio couldn't show a preview of the drawable which i made before.

[image: AS's Preview pane is empty]

Comment: have you tried changing version number?.if not then try decreasing it and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is not showing preview when `state_pressed=true`. Replace `true` to `false` to enable the "show preview".

Answer (score 2):

[image]

See the upper Image click on `Version 24` and select `Version 23` or below it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This
    
is only drawable when item is pressed

So remove `state_pressed=true`

or add not state item

```
<item>
...
</item>
```